# Moving NPCs from house to house?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I cannot get an NPC to move from his current house, to a more convenient option. The house he currently lives in now has no light, walls, chairs or tables, yet he still lives there. Why?

Answer (score 1):

There's no button or any real way of changing an NPC's housing without making the house completely inhabitable. (Or killing them.)

Comment: Uninhabitable, surely?